# How can I change a button's color on hover?

Tags: css, button, hover

I need to change the color of a button on hover.

Here is my solution, but it doesn't work.

```
a.button {
   display: -moz-inline-stack;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 391px;
   height: 62px;
   background: url("img/btncolor.png") no-repeat;
   line-height: 62px;
   vertical-align: text-middle;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ebe6eb;
   font-family: Zenhei;
   font-size: 39px;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   text-shadow: #222222 1px 1px 0;
}
a.button a:hover{
     background: #383;
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`a.button a:hover` means "a link that's being hovered over that is a child of a link with the class `button`".

Go instead for `a.button:hover`.

Answer (score 22):

Seems your selector is wrong, try using:

```
a.button:hover{
     background: #383;
}
```

Your code

```
a.button a:hover
```

Means it is going to search for an `a` element inside `a` with class button.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.button:hover{
    background: #383;  }
```

works  for me but in my case

```
#buttonClick:hover {
background-color:green;  }
```