# How do I make a button red when I hover across the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't get a button to change color on hover. Can anyone help here?

Comment: What have you tried? Evidence of effort on your part will be much appreciated by the denizens of this site.

Comment: 0.01 seconds of google: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover You type it up yourself. We're not here to enable your laziness.

Comment: where is that button/?

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing a button color on hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898781/changing-a-button-color-on-hover)

Comment: You should check out [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple stuff.  In the future please add the code you are having trouble with in your question, so it will be easier for us to help.

CSS:

```css
.btn {
  background:#fff;
  }

.btn:hover {
  
  background:#f00;
  }
```

HTML

```
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: Thank You! Im new to StackOverflow and wanted to know this because its part of my project for school!

Comment: No problem! Welcome to SO!  After asking your question and getting the answer you were looking for, make sure to select that answer as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the post.  It helps people find answers in the future!

Comment: Hey Pavel, don't forget to choose an answer when your problem has been solved! If it hasn't been solved, please update your question!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to make a button. I'm guessing you're not styling the right one.

```
input[type=button]:hover,input[type=submit]:hover,button:hover
{
  background-color: red;
}
```