# Change background of a button when I hover it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

How can I make the background image of a button change  when I hover it? Maybe make the image fade from left to right? Is this "doable"?

Answer (score 1):

On your initial button style
you have the {background:url('image1.jpeg'); width:100%;}.  then CREATE another style called #button:hover {background:url('image2.jpeg);}
Your 'maybe' effect can be achieved by adding a transition to your style #button

Answer (score 0):

An example code snap:

```
<button id="buttonID">Search</button>

<style>
#buttonID:hover
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
enter code here
</style>
```

Simply give an ID or class and in stylesheet #elementID:hover name of that button.

Answer (score 0):

This answer solves it quite nicely, not sure about the fading in from left to right, but I'm sure it's possible I just don't know css that well

[How can I change a button's color on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898781/how-can-i-change-a-buttons-color-on-hover)

You want the background variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do with Linear gradient (maybe you can do with a image!!(or not))

```css
  
    #btn{
            width:20%;
            border: solid 1px rgba(171, 156, 156, 0.56);
            border-radius:15px;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #2ede13 50%,#7ed755 50%);
            background-size: 200% 100%;
            background-position: right bottom;
            transition-property: all;
            transition: 1s;
        }
    
            #btn:hover {
                background-position: left bottom;
                color: black;
            }
```

```html
 <button id="btn">Search</button>
```

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/how-do-i-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradient-on-the-same-element