# How to make HTML button darken when hovered over?

Tags: html, wordpress, button

I'm looking to make a html button darken in colour when hovered over.

The code I'm using is below:

```
<div style="width: 200px; color: white; background-color: #bf8f42; opacity: 0.8; margin: auto; margin-top: 0px; padding: 20px;">Training</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change a button's color on hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898781/how-can-i-change-a-buttons-color-on-hover)

Comment: By not searching SO's vast archive of existing answers before posting your question, you waste your own time and the time of others who help you and who moderate you.  Please practice better SO citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this part of code:

```
<style>
div:hover{
background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Ill take that with me

Answer (score 1):

you can give a class to your div element and add some styling in style tag in  tag.
Here is full HTML code for the button with a bit darken on hover

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
.btn-training
{
width: 200px; 
color: white; 
background-color: #bf8f42; 
opacity: 0.8; 
margin:0 auto;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
.btn-training:hover
{
background-color: #9f7f31;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn-training">Training</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

When the user hovers over the class (test) it triggers the css element .test:hover. :hover is a anchor pseudo-class. you can use these types of classes in various ways [Shown Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

```css
.test:hover {
    background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">text</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: K, will do. But also every other answer on this question doesn't have a explanation of what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
div:hover{
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you for changing colors while hovering

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

       <input type="button"  /> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this solution:
    .btn-test {
      width: 200px;
      color: white;
      background-color: #bf8f42;
      opacity: 0.8;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 0px;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .btn-test:hover {
      background-color: #a26d19;
    }
 <div class="btn-test">Training</div>
```

Comment: This worked, however I can't seem to increase the button size plus it moves another button the the right. @vinod joshi

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.