# How can I add hover effect to this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add hover effect to the `button`​ like when I hover it its change the background color to #63A244 and the text color to white - #FFFFFF . Thanks in advance.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    "palette": {
      "popup": {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "text": "#63a244"
      },
      "button": {
        "background": "transparent",
        "text": "#63a244",
        "border": "#63a244"
      }
    },
    "position": "top",
    "content": {
      "message": "Cookies Massage",
      "dismiss": "OK",
      "link": "Read More",
      "href": "#"
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css" />
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Why don't you simpley use .addClass or .css ?

Comment: i dont know you can help me do it ? i try to use <style> but i cant fint the javascript to do what i type in style like i tryed :

Comment: Probably, you need to check with `:hover` [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) in css

Comment: .button
#button
(button)
"button"

Comment: i tryed its not worked

Comment: is it required that you use only JS? because for minor things like background color is the way to go...

Comment: button:hover { background-color:#63A244; color:#FFFFFF; } This on css @BlackB1RD

Comment: .button:hover (not work) #button:hover (not work) (button):hover (not work) "button":hover(not work)

Comment: @Flowen its not worked maybe i have a error in my code ?

Comment: also, check the rendered DOM, what you are seeing as a button could be a span or a div...

Comment: Instead of using the CDN version, [host your own copy with a modified stylesheet](https://github.com/insites/cookieconsent).

Comment: Definitely don't need javascript for something simple like that keep it easy use css hover. 

a:hover {styles here}

Comment: i post the full code down here if u can check if i have error in the code i will be more then happy ! @Flowen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change a button's color on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898781/how-can-i-change-a-buttons-color-on-hover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you're using external css files that use a override every style that you're using. Look at this JSFiddle, it will do the trick for you :)

I just copy your code and found what element is generated by the JS. Then I apply some style on it.

```
a.cc-dismiss{
  transition:all .25s;
}
a.cc-dismiss:hover{
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color:#63A244;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cpg0uL31/

Comment: More informations if you're not getting it : a.cc-dismiss = an "a" tag in html with the "cc-dismiss" class on it.

Comment: I hope you get why you were not able to apply previous answer :) Don't hesitate to share JSFiddle link with your code, it will help us next time to give you information faster ! Have a great day

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try something like below with simple `hover` css.

```css
.myButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="hover me" class="myButton">
```

Comment: i post the full code here maybe i have a error in the code if u can check

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `:hover selector` should do it.

```
button:hover {
   background-color: #63A244;
   color: white;
}
```

More info: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp)

Comment: not worked i post the full code maybe i have error in the code ?

Comment: try his code without the dot... like: button:hover { background-color: #63A244; color: white; } and add ";" after the color

Comment: not worked i edit the post and add the full code check it out cause its not work for me the example you give me

Comment: i add to the post the full code check it out cause the code u give me to pot in the <style> not worked !

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mouseOver() {
  $("#btn").addClass("text bg");
  $("#btn").text("your text");
}

function mouseOut() {
  $("#btn").removeClass('text bg')
  $("#btn").text("Mouse over me");
}
```

```css
.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFF;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #63A244;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">Mouse over me</button>
```