# Button color change on hover CSS

Tags: css

The subject exists on Stackoverflow but I don't understand my problem in CSS.

[How can I change a button's color on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898781/how-can-i-change-a-buttons-color-on-hover)

I have a `login` button, when I wish to hover the button. One white background should appears.

I get a small background color.

```css
body{

    background-image: url("https://zupimages.net/up/20/20/vreu.jpg");
    height: 550px;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
      
}
 .header-btn-register-login{
 margin-top: 220px;
 margin-left: 538px;
 display: flex;
 font-size: 26px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;

}


.btn-login {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
   border: solid 3px;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 12px 18px;
}

 .btn-login a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}



.btn-login a:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-btn-register-login">
     <div class="btn-login"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change so that you hoover the button and not the a tag to change the background. And then you should change the color of the a tag. Example css below.

```
.btn-login:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.btn-login:hover a {
     color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use " .btn-login:hover " instead of ".btn-login a:hover" , this is going to work .

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the background color of `.btn-login` not `.btn-login a`

```
.btn-login:hover {
   background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the hover on your `a` tag, that's why your background-color changes when you hover the `a`. You can change as following:

```css
body{

    background-image: url("https://zupimages.net/up/20/20/vreu.jpg");
    height: 550px;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
      
}
 .header-btn-register-login{
 margin-top: 220px;
 margin-left: 538px;
 display: flex;
 font-size: 26px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;

}


.btn-login {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
   border: solid 3px;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 12px 18px;
}

 .btn-login a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}


/* Here are the modified css */
.btn-login:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

.btn-login:hover a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-btn-register-login">
     <div class="btn-login"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are given the hover effect for a inside the button . Thats why only a is changing the color on hover. Change the line to :

```
.btn-login:hover {
   background-color: #ffffff;  ( Your desired color )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're not using a button but an `<a>` element, so when you change the background for the `<a>` element only the background of the writing changes. To change the background of the whole 'pseudo' button you need to change the background color of the `<div>` containing the `<a>` element while changing also the `<a>` element.

Your code modified accordingly to what said above:

```css
body{
    background-image: url("https://zupimages.net/up/20/20/vreu.jpg");
    height: 550px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative; 
}

 .header-btn-register-login{
 margin-top: 220px;
 margin-left: 538px;
 display: flex;
 font-size: 26px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;

}

.btn-login {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
   border: solid 3px;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 12px 18px;
}

 .btn-login a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-login:hover{
 color: black;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

.btn-login:hover a{
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-btn-register-login">
     <div class="btn-login"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
    </div>
```