# css change button color when hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the text color to black from white when the button is hover and every thing good in the code except that the text color does not change. does someone know how do I make it work?

```css
.main__btn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 15px 50px;
  border-radius: none;
  border-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="main__btn" id="button1"><a href="#">button1</a></button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change a button's color on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898781/how-can-i-change-a-buttons-color-on-hover)

Comment: An anchor inside a button is invalid. There's no reason to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to change `color` on anchor (`a`) tag, not `button`.

```css
.main__btn:hover a {
  color: #000;
}
```

As you have set `color: #fff;` on anchor tag above, preventing inheritance of `color` of `.main__btn:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag's color is white. Applying `color:#000` on the parent will not change its color.

Instead, apply `color:#000` to the anchor.

```css
.main__btn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 15px 50px;
  border-radius: none;
  border-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover a{
  color: #000;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="main__btn" id="button1"><a href="#">button1</a></button>
```

Do take note however that having an anchor in a button is invalid HTML.<sub>- [Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6022243/roy)</sub>

Comment: @Spectric The HTML is invalid. You should also mention that in your answer.